# Need help converting TradingView Pine script from Version 2 to Version 4

Tags: variables, pine-script

I am new to TradingView Pine scripting. I am working on some study/strategy but currently seeking for help with a pine script which is on version 2 right now but I am trying convert it into Version 4 and is having so many compilation errors.

Below is the complete script I am trying to convert from V2 to V2 and error I am facing.

**Script**

```
//@version=4
//Trend Trading Study by MSM *Sanjay.r* Trend Trading Indicator
study("MystockMoney Trend Trading Tool 1.0", overlay=true)
res = input(title="Main MSM Time Frame", type=resolution, defval="120")
Factor=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)
Pd=input(1, minval=1,maxval = 100)
tp = input(500,title="Take Profit")
sl = input(200,title="Stop Loss")
//Plots VWAP and MVWAP for intraday trading. Useful to avoid whipsaws
//study("VWAP MVWAP with pivot points", overlay = true)
avlen = input(50) 
color1 = blue
color2 = black
mvwap = ema(vwap,avlen)
plot(vwap,linewidth = 2,style = circles, color = color2)
plot(mvwap,color= color1)
Up=hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd))
Dn=hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd))
MUp=security(tickerid,res,hl2-(Factor*atr(Pd)))
MDn=security(tickerid,res,hl2+(Factor*atr(Pd)))
Mclose=security(tickerid,res,close)
TrendUp=close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown=close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
MTrendUp=Mclose[1]>MTrendUp[1]? max(MUp,MTrendUp[1]) : MUp
MTrendDown=Mclose[1]<MTrendDown[1]? min(MDn,MTrendDown[1]) : MDn
Trend = close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown
MTrend = Mclose > MTrendDown[1] ? 1: Mclose< MTrendUp[1]? -1: nz(MTrend[1],1)
MTsl = MTrend==1? MTrendUp: MTrendDown
linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red
plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "MSM")
Mlinecolor = MTrend == 1 ? blue : orange
plot(MTsl, color = Mlinecolor , style = line , linewidth = 2,title = "Main MSM")
plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, red,0,0)
up = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and MTrend == 1 
down = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 and MTrend == -1 
plotarrow(up ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(down ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
golong = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and MTrend == 1 
goshort = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 and MTrend == -1 
length=input(21, "length", minval=1)
avrg=sma(volume,length)
vold1 = volume > avrg*1.5 and close<open
vold2 = volume >= avrg*0.5 and volume<=avrg*1.5 and close<open
vold3 = volume < avrg *0.5 and close<open
volu1 = volume > avrg*1.5 and close>open
volu2 = volume >= avrg*0.5 and volume<=avrg*1.5 and close>open
volu3 = volume< avrg*0.5 and close>open
cold1=#800000
cold2=#FF0000
cold3=orange
colu1=#006400
colu2=lime
colu3=#7FFFD4
color = vold1 ? cold1 : vold2 ? cold2 : vold3 ? cold3 : volu1 ? colu1 : volu2 ? colu2 : volu3 ? colu3 : na
barcolor(color)
//Code merged for another indicator
sd = input(true, title="Show Daily Pivots?")
//Pivot Range Calculations - Mark Fisher
pivot = (high + low + close ) / 3.0 
bc = (high + low ) / 2.0 
tc = (pivot - bc) + pivot
r1 = (pivot * 2) - low
s1 = (pivot * 2) - high
r2 = pivot + (high - low)
s2 = pivot - (high - low)
r3 = r1 + (high - low)
s3 = s1 - (high - low)
r4 = r3 + (r2 - r1)
s4 = s3 - (s1 - s2)
//Daily Pivot Range 
dtime_pivot = security(tickerid, 'D', pivot[1]) 
dtime_bc = security(tickerid, 'D', bc[1]) 
dtime_tc = security(tickerid, 'D', tc[1]) 
dtime_r1 = security(tickerid, 'D', r1[1])
dtime_r2 = security(tickerid, 'D', r2[1])
dtime_r3 = security(tickerid, 'D', r3[1])
dtime_r4 = security(tickerid, 'D', r4[1])
dtime_s1 = security(tickerid, 'D', s1[1])
dtime_s2 = security(tickerid, 'D', s2[1])
dtime_s3 = security(tickerid, 'D', s3[1])
dtime_s4 = security(tickerid, 'D', s4[1])
offs_daily = 0 
plot(sd and dtime_pivot ? dtime_pivot : na, title="Daily Pivot",style=circles, color=blue,linewidth=3) 
plot(sd and dtime_bc ? dtime_bc : na, title="Daily BC",style=circles, color=blue,linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_tc ? dtime_tc : na, title="Daily TC",style=circles, color=blue,linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_r1 ? dtime_r1 : na, title="Daily r1",style=circles, color=green,linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_s1 ? dtime_s1 : na, title="Daily s1",style=circles, color=red,linewidth=3)
```

**Errors after compiling above script**

```
Processing script...
line 5: Undeclared identifier 'resolution';
line 18: Undeclared identifier 'blue';
line 19: Undeclared identifier 'black';
line 21: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 21: Undeclared identifier 'color2';
line 22: Undeclared identifier 'color1';
line 26: Undeclared identifier 'res';
line 27: Undeclared identifier 'res';
line 29: Undeclared identifier 'res';
line 31: Undeclared identifier 'TrendUp';
line 32: Undeclared identifier 'TrendDown';
line 34: Undeclared identifier 'Mclose';
line 34: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendUp';
line 34: Undeclared identifier 'MUp';
line 35: Undeclared identifier 'Mclose';
line 35: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendDown';
line 35: Undeclared identifier 'MDn';
line 37: Undeclared identifier 'TrendDown';
line 37: Undeclared identifier 'TrendUp';
line 37: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 38: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 38: Undeclared identifier 'TrendUp';
line 38: Undeclared identifier 'TrendDown';
line 40: Undeclared identifier 'Mclose';
line 40: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendDown';
line 40: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendUp';
line 40: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 41: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 41: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendUp';
line 41: Undeclared identifier 'MTrendDown';
line 43: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 43: Undeclared identifier 'green';
line 43: Undeclared identifier 'red';
line 44: Undeclared identifier 'Tsl';
line 44: Undeclared identifier 'linecolor';
line 44: Undeclared identifier 'line';
line 46: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 46: Undeclared identifier 'blue';
line 46: Undeclared identifier 'orange';
line 47: Undeclared identifier 'MTsl';
line 47: Undeclared identifier 'Mlinecolor';
line 47: Undeclared identifier 'line';
line 49: Undeclared identifier 'Tsl';
line 49: Undeclared identifier 'green';
line 50: Undeclared identifier 'Tsl';
line 50: Undeclared identifier 'red';
line 52: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 52: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 53: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 53: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 54: Undeclared identifier 'up';
line 54: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 54: Undeclared identifier 'lime';
line 55: Undeclared identifier 'down';
line 55: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 55: Undeclared identifier 'red';
line 58: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 58: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 59: Undeclared identifier 'Trend';
line 59: Undeclared identifier 'MTrend';
line 76: Undeclared identifier 'orange';
line 80: Undeclared identifier 'lime';
line 84: Undeclared identifier 'cold3';
line 84: Undeclared identifier 'colu2';
line 86: Undeclared identifier 'color';
line 105: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 106: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 107: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 108: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 109: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 110: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 111: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 112: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 113: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 114: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 115: Cannot call 'security' with arguments (const integer, literal string, series[float]); available overloads: security(string, string, series[float], const bool, const bool, string) => series[float]; security(string, string, series[integer], const bool, const bool, string) => series[integer]; security(string, string, series[bool], const bool, const bool, string) => series[bool]; security(string, string, series[color], const bool, const bool, string) => series[color]; security(string, string, <arg_expr_type>, const bool, const bool, string) => <arg_expr_type>;
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'dtime_pivot';
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 119: Undeclared identifier 'blue';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'dtime_bc';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 120: Undeclared identifier 'blue';
line 121: Undeclared identifier 'dtime_tc';
line 121: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 121: Undeclared identifier 'blue';
line 122: Undeclared identifier 'dtime_r1';
line 122: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 122: Undeclared identifier 'green';
line 123: Undeclared identifier 'dtime_s1';
line 123: Undeclared identifier 'circles';
line 123: Undeclared identifier 'red'
Script 'MystockMoney Trend Trading Tool 1.0' has been saved
```

Answer (score 1):

Converted to Pine `v4`

```
//@version=4
//Trend Trading Study by MSM *Sanjay.r* Trend Trading Indicator
study("MystockMoney Trend Trading Tool 1.0", overlay=true)

res     = input(title="Main MSM Time Frame", type=input.resolution, defval="120")
Factor  = input(1,   minval = 1, maxval = 100)
Pd      = input(1,   minval = 1, maxval = 100)
tp      = input(500, title="Take Profit")
sl      = input(200, title="Stop Loss")
avlen   = input(50) 

var float   TrendUp     = na
var float   TrendDown   = na
var float   MTrendUp    = na
var float   MTrendDown  = na
var float   Trend       = na
var float   Tsl         = na
var float   MTrend      = na
var float   MTsl        = na
var color   linecolor   = na

//Plots VWAP and MVWAP for intraday trading. Useful to avoid whipsaws
//study("VWAP MVWAP with pivot points", overlay = true)
color1      = color.blue
color2      = color.black
mvwap       = ema(vwap,avlen)

plot(vwap, linewidth = 2, style = plot.style_circles, color = color2)
plot(mvwap, color= color1)

delta       = (Factor*atr(Pd))
Up          = hl2 - delta
Dn          = hl2 + delta

MUp         = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, Up)
MDn         = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, Dn)
Mclose      = security(syminfo.tickerid, res, close)

TrendUp     := close[1]>TrendUp[1]? max(Up,TrendUp[1]) : Up
TrendDown   := close[1]<TrendDown[1]? min(Dn,TrendDown[1]) : Dn
MTrendUp    := Mclose[1]>MTrendUp[1]? max(MUp,MTrendUp[1]) : MUp
MTrendDown  := Mclose[1]<MTrendDown[1]? min(MDn,MTrendDown[1]) : MDn
Trend       := close > TrendDown[1] ? 1: close< TrendUp[1]? -1: nz(Trend[1],1)
Tsl         := Trend==1? TrendUp: TrendDown
MTrend      := Mclose > MTrendDown[1] ? 1: Mclose< MTrendUp[1]? -1: nz(MTrend[1],1)
MTsl        := MTrend==1? MTrendUp: MTrendDown
linecolor   := Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red

plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2, title = "MSM")

Mlinecolor  = MTrend == 1 ? color.blue : color.orange

plot(MTsl, color = Mlinecolor , style = plot.style_line , linewidth = 2,title = "Main MSM")
plotshape(cross(close,Tsl) and close>Tsl , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar, color.green, 0, 0)
plotshape(cross(Tsl,close) and close<Tsl , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown , location.abovebar, color.red, 0, 0)

up          = Trend == 1 and Trend[1] == -1 and MTrend == 1 
down        = Trend == -1 and Trend[1] == 1 and MTrend == -1 

plotarrow(up ? Trend : na, title="Up Entry Arrow", colorup=color.lime, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)
plotarrow(down ? Trend : na, title="Down Entry Arrow", colordown=color.red, maxheight=60, minheight=50, transp=0)

golong      = up
goshort     = down

length      = input(21, "length", minval=1)

avrg        = sma(volume, length)

vold1       = volume >  avrg*1.5 and close < open
vold2       = volume >= avrg*0.5 and volume <= avrg*1.5 and close < open
vold3       = volume <  avrg*0.5 and close < open
volu1       = volume >  avrg*1.5 and close > open
volu2       = volume >= avrg*0.5 and volume <= avrg*1.5 and close > open
volu3       = volume <  avrg*0.5 and close > open

cold1       = #800000
cold2       = #FF0000
cold3       = color.orange
colu1       = #006400
colu2       = color.lime
colu3       = #7FFFD4

bcolor      = vold1 ? cold1 : vold2 ? cold2 : vold3 ? cold3 : volu1 ? colu1 : volu2 ? colu2 : volu3 ? colu3 : na

barcolor(bcolor)

//Code merged for another indicator
sd          = input(true, title="Show Daily Pivots?")

//Pivot Range Calculations - Mark Fisher
pivot       = hlc3
bc          = hl2
tc          = (pivot - bc) + pivot
r1          = (pivot * 2) - low
s1          = (pivot * 2) - high
r2          = pivot + (high - low)
s2          = pivot - (high - low)
r3          = r1 + (high - low)
s3          = s1 - (high - low)
r4          = r3 + (r2 - r1)
s4          = s3 - (s1 - s2)

//Daily Pivot Range 
dtime_pivot = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', pivot[1]) 
dtime_bc    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', bc[1]) 
dtime_tc    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', tc[1]) 
dtime_r1    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', r1[1])
dtime_r2    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', r2[1])
dtime_r3    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', r3[1])
dtime_r4    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', r4[1])
dtime_s1    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', s1[1])
dtime_s2    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', s2[1])
dtime_s3    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', s3[1])
dtime_s4    = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', s4[1])

offs_daily  = 0 

plot(sd and dtime_pivot ? dtime_pivot : na, title="Daily Pivot", style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue,  linewidth=3) 
plot(sd and dtime_bc    ? dtime_bc    : na, title="Daily BC",    style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue,  linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_tc    ? dtime_tc    : na, title="Daily TC",    style=plot.style_circles, color=color.blue,  linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_r1    ? dtime_r1    : na, title="Daily r1",    style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, linewidth=3)
plot(sd and dtime_s1    ? dtime_s1    : na, title="Daily s1",    style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red,   linewidth=3)
```